# kubernetes and cert-manager certificates limit number

Tags: kubernetes

I am using cert-manager to manager SSL certificates on kubernetes.
Certificates are stored as secrets in my namespace.
I'll have to generate near 1 000+ certificates but I read that it is "dangerous" to have a high number of secrets because it could block start of kubernetes when starting new nodes for example.

Do you have more information about how many secrets could be critical ?
How many certificates are you managing by cert-manager and is your k8s cluster safe ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any information about the exact secret's number, but after check the [oficial documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#restrictions) I've found:

> Individual secrets are limited to 1MiB in size. This is to discourage creation of very large secrets which would exhaust the API server and kubelet memory. However, **creation of many smaller secrets could also exhaust memory**. More comprehensive limits on memory usage due to secrets is a planned feature.

Is hard to say a magical number because It will depends of how are you using the secrets and how your cluster is configured. The most safe way is test in a non-production environment to verify the behaviour. A multimaster or multicluster cluster could be more resilient to handle secrets, for example.

In gke dimension limits: number of pods, number of services + total number of objects stored in [etcd](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/best-practices/scalability#dimension_limits.).

[Here](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.4.0/faq/) you can find more information about etcd databases and K8s API requirements/performance.

Also, I found a very interesting [article](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/sig-scalability/configs-and-limits/thresholds.md) where we can find more information about Kubernetes scalability thresholds, unfortunately there is no mention about k8s secrets performace.

Comment: That's it, that's what I read too ! Unformunatly I can't seem to find an order of value, which would be helpful.